# running tmux automatically when xterm is launched: what is the most elegant/correct solution?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, tmux, xterm

I am trying to setup my workstation in such a way that [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) is run for each terminal (`xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, ...) that is launched. I was thinking to add `tmux` to the `.bashrc`; problem is that if I launch `bash` twice for whatever reason, it start a second `tmux` inside the current `tmux`.

So:

- is there a way to detect, maybe from the `.bashrc`, that the current bash is the 'first' one  and not a second one launched in the same terminal?
- any other good ideas / best practices / bash design patterns?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your `.bash_profile`:

```
SHELL=tmux
```

This is the first place `xterm` checks for the command to run if none is given on the command line.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work. Do you have any idea why? I added it both to `.bashrc` and to `.bash_profile`.

Comment: hmm, actually it seems to work only if xterm is started from a shell that has defined $SHELL as tmux. Interesting...

Comment: Then it's probably time to mention the caveat. If you log into the machine using a graphical login, then you probably don't have a bash shell as the ultimate ancestor of all your processes. It's been a while for me; is there something like `.xinitrc` or a Gnome/KDE equivalent to which you can add the `SHELL=tmux` setting?

Answer (score 1):

Combine the two previous answers:

```
alias xterm='SHELL=tmux xterm'
```

You get the desired behavior when starting just `xterm`, but you can still use xterm for other operations, such as `xterm top`.

Answer (score 0):

What about aliasing `xterm` to `xterm tmux`?

Just add the following line to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias xterm='xterm tmux'
```

Comment: thanks, but it does not seem a correct solution because I might want to use xterm for purposes that are different than launching a shell. For example `xterm top`. So, my goal is probably to be able to use tmux as default xterm shell.

Comment: @francescostablum: So, create a different alias, e.g. `xtt`.

Comment: yes, this might actually be a solution, but I have to define several aliases for all terminal types that I want to use with `tmux`.

Answer (score 0):

Only during login, Bash will execute ~/.bash_profile which should include ~/.bashrc, but should never use exit or session will be ended. If ~/.bash_profile does not exist, then ~/.bash_login is executed. If neither ~/.bash_profile nor ~/.bash_login exists, then ~/.profile is executed. I like to use ~/.bash_login.

Therefore, ~/.bash_login should include:

```bash
# use tmux instead of xterm
if [[ -z "$DISPLAY" ]] \
      && [[ "$TERM" != tmux* ]] \
      && hash tmux 2>/dev/null; then
  exec tmux new-session
fi
```

Note: ~/.bashrc is executed by bash if you are already logged in.